# Изучение ajax

Tags: ajax, javascript

Привет, народ.

Слушайте, хочу изучить AJAX. Походу нужен какой-то сервер, куда будет отпраляться все это добро. Как мне тестировать примеры на компе? Я только новичок, так что не смейтесь. И второй вопрос. Можно делать сайты через Ajax без XML, а только JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тестируется на обычном Денвере. В принципе, на всем что поддеживает Php для приема. Если работать через jquery (советую и рекомендую именно так - для новичка), то там можно указывать формат json и работать с ним. В помощь jquery-docs.ru.

**Добавлено из комментария**.

Для примера примерно такой js код для отправки ajax запроса:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json", // Формат ожидаемого ответа
    url: "ajax.php",  // Куда посылаешь
    data: ({
        x: 5,
        y: 10
    }), // Какие данные передаешь
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data); // выводишь в консоль ответ сервера
    }
});
```

ajax.php - это php скрипт, куда будут падать запросы и обрабатываться.

http://jquery-docs.ru/Ajax/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Перенесено в ответ.

Comment: ПАСИБ сейчас установлю денвера

Comment: Нда... Задан вопрос с меткой "javascript". Пример кода на jQuery... Куда катится мир?

Comment: @ImirofF А что, jQuery уже переписали на VBScript?

Answer (score 0):

[Лутчий туториал](http://kaidez.com/ajax-tutorial/) для начинающих по AJAX который я видел, начиная от истоков, истории до примеров выполнения AJAX запросов на чистом `javascript`

Comment: Только туториал на английском, а вопрос был задан на русскоязычном SO. И лучший-ли он - это вопрос "религии"

Comment: Как я уже написал, лутчий который я видел, мое личное мнение, и на правду не претендую. А по поводу английского, то без этого ни куда, 99% всего материала в сети на английском, понимание технического английского очень важен, ну и кроме всего, примеры ведь на javascript